# Is this the correct way of combining selectors using createSelector?

Tags: javascript, redux, reselect

I would like to combine selectors using reselectJS but my code looks a little different than in the examples, and was wondering if I was using the library correctly?

```
const makeSelectCurrentPosition = () =>
  createSelector(selectGlobal, globalState => globalState.current_position);

const makeSelectSKU = () =>
  createSelector(makeSelectCurrentPosition(), substate => {
    console.log('substate is: ', JSON.stringify(substate));
    return substate.sku;
  });

const makeSelectQualityLabel = () =>
  createSelector(
    makeSelectCurrentPosition(),
    substate => substate.quality_label,
  );

const makeSelectMerchant = () =>
  createSelector(
    makeSelectCurrentPosition(),
    substate => substate.merchant_name,
  );

const makeSelectZRSStatus = () =>
  createSelector(makeSelectCurrentPosition(), substate => substate.zrsStatus);

const makeSelectPositionId = () =>
  createSelector(makeSelectCurrentPosition(), substate => substate.id);
```

In the example is seems as though they do not call the function but just provide i.e. makeSelectCurrentPosition instead of makeSelectCurrentPosition() (no brackets) however when I try this substate is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

No, you definitely should not call the input selector parameter, just provide the selector function.
The function `createSelector` is taking variable number of input parameters - the all of them but not the last one are selectors. And the last parameter is always a combiner of the previous parameters. The combiner is a function where the input parameters are evaluted values of the selectors (the previous parameteres), eg:

```js
// subtotalSelector and taxPercentSelector are other previously defined selectors
const taxSelector = createSelector(
  subtotalSelector,
  taxPercentSelector,
  // subtotal and taxPercent are evaluated values of subtotalSelector and taxPercentSelector
  (subtotal, taxPercent) => subtotal * (taxPercent / 100)
)

// this is another correct syntax for the same example
const taxSelector = createSelector(
  [subtotalSelector, taxPercentSelector],
  (subtotal, taxPercent) => subtotal * (taxPercent / 100)
)
```

The entry point of your next selectors is the reducer state and optionally component props, in your example I did not see it.
Try to create first selector with use of the redux state, eg:

```js
const makeSelectCurrentPosition = (state) => state.current_position;
```

Then you can use it in your mapStateToProps (in case you are using react-redux), this way:

```js
mapStateToProps = state => {
  selectCurrentPosition: makeSelectCurrentPosition(state)
}
```

Comment: So I think I might be misunderstanding something, I do have a simple state selector at the top of my class.

Comment: Do you mean `selectGlobal`? Can you post relevant code, how are you setting that `selectGlobal`? And also code - how are you using your defined selectors in your code?